# HTML fails to load images when all files in Google Docs

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, png

When my HTML and PNG files are all in a GoogleDocs folder the HTML fails to load images.  When the exact same files are in a local folder images load correctly. Since all files are in the same folder I specify them without path information.  Why is this happening and is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this out: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en and https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=38083

Basically, you have to make sure all of the resources that you are trying to access are `public` and accessible on the web by anyone. If they are not, the browser will not be able to fetch the resource and load it in.